# Flutter Keyboard Detect Visibility

Tags: flutter

I want to detect if the keyboard is visible. I could implement the hacks that were suggested on other stackoverlfow threads:

bool keyboardvisible = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0;

and this works for Android, but on iOS this bottom property always seems to return 0, no matter if the keyboard is visible or not.

Is there any better approach to detect keyboard visibility that actually works on both platforms?

Thnx
John

Comment: I am not sure how you are doing it but it is working for me in iOS.

Comment: [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_visibility) should help you

Answer (score 1):

[this plugin will help you.](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_visibility) It provides a listener for visibility change for both iOS and Android.

Example Code:

```dart
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

@protected
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
      print(visible);
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, found that one. But I also really would like to know why IOS and Android behave inconsistently when using this MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom property....

Comment: ohh. I have no idea for that.